# extract strings from HTML tag pandas

Tags: python, pandas, text-extraction

How do I extract the following strings using str.extract or regex or any efficient way using python pandas in this tags below

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/download/iphone" rel="nofollow">Twitter for iPhone</a>
<a href="http://twitter.com" rel="nofollow">Twitter Web Client</a>
<a href="http://vine.co" rel="nofollow">Vine - Make a Scene</a>
<a href="https://about.twitter.com/products/tweetdeck" rel="nofollow">TweetDeck</a>
```

am using:
.str.extract('(>[A-Za-z])<')

I want this output:
Twitter for iPhone
Twitter Web Client
Vine - Make a Scene
TweetDeck

Comment: Are the strings in a pandas dataframe?

Comment: Would each row of you Dataframe have a single html element or could there be multiple?

Comment: @C. pappy yes in a df

Comment: each row of the df has a single element @rayad

Comment: From what you've shared the html is pretty standard (reliably consistent pattern). I would just do `.str.split('>').str[1].str.split('<').str[0]`

Comment: @rayad you have 4 `str` accessors, its probably more efficient to use a loop ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thie might help:

```
import pandas as pd
lst = [
    ['<a href="http://twitter.com/download/iphone" rel="nofollow">Twitter for iPhone</a>'],
    ['<a href="http://twitter.com" rel="nofollow">Twitter Web Client</a>'],
    ['<a href="http://vine.co" rel="nofollow">Vine - Make a Scene</a>'],
    ['<a href="https://about.twitter.com/products/tweetdeck" rel="nofollow">TweetDeck</a>']
]

df = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns=['url'])
df['text'] = df['url'].str.extract(r'>(.*?)<')
print(df)
```

Output

```
                                                 url                 text
0  <a href="http://twitter.com/download/iphone" r...   Twitter for iPhone
1  <a href="http://twitter.com" rel="nofollow">Tw...   Twitter Web Client
2  <a href="http://vine.co" rel="nofollow">Vine -...  Vine - Make a Scene
3  <a href="https://about.twitter.com/products/tw...            TweetDeck
```

Comment: str.extract('(>[A-Za-z])<')       I was using this and it wasnt working thanks alot this ur answer worked

Comment: BTW, SO encourages posters of include any code they have tried with their questions. Please upvote my answer since you accepted it.

Comment: alright I'll take that into account thank you very much

Comment: It says I need at least 15 reps to upvote ur answer